# Are apache log file entries guaranteed to be sequential in time?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

And if yes, are they ordered by the time the request was received ([`%t`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats)) or the time the request was fulfilled (`%t+%T`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. They are ordered by `%t+%T` so you may have one line `A` appearing after another line `B` but `A` has an earlier `%t` than `B`.

Comment: Further question: are they always ordered by `%t+%T`, even under heavy load with a lot of worker processes/threads?

Comment: @netvope No, they are not guaranteed to be ordered by by %t+%T (they just usually are). The time calculation and log writing are not protected by an exclusive and atomic locking mechanism so a context switch may happen. N.B. under apache 1.3 log lines were more likely to in in the "correct" order. You can get the same effect in 2.x by compiling with I_INSIST_ON_EXTRA_CYCLES_FOR_CLF_COMPLIANCE defined. However, there is still a chance for out-of-order lines.